# Can you offer prizes, cash and/or products, to say the person w/highest score on an iphone game app?

Tags: iphone

Does apple allow that? I remember a $30K contest that a team from MIT ended up winning. I think it had to do with locating red balloons on a GPS that were scattered all over the world. Something like that.

Comment: I think you're thinking of this MIT contest, which wasn't anything to do with iPhones specifically http://balloon.media.mit.edu

Comment: Aside from the Apple Ts & Cs, you'd also need to ensure you comply with laws on such contests in the jurisdictions you're planning to give the prizes. Probably a minefield, and not exactly an on-topic question for StackOverflow...

Answer (score 7):

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> - Contests, sweepstakes, lotteries, and raffles
>
> 1 Sweepstakes and contests must be sponsored by the developer/company of
>   the app
>   2 Official rules for sweepstakes and contests, must be presented in the
>   app and make it clear that Apple is
>   not a sponsor or involved in the
>   activity in any manner
>   3 It must be permissible by law for the developer to run a lottery app,
>   and a lottery app must have all of the
>   following characteristics:
>   consideration, chance, and a prize
>   4 Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle
>   ticket in the app will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they wouldn't, but if you offer anything of value on your "game" I'm almost 100% sure that hackers will find a way to the top =/.

Comment: Thanks! Something to think about

Answer (score 0):

As long as the game continues to function after the competition period you should be fine